# Separating a list by eol when parsing ocaml

Tags: ocaml, menhir

I have defined some statements followed by a list of expressions in my compiler. I am using Menhir for the parsing. Typically when lexing `EOL` it does this:
`| eol { incr_linenum lexbuf; read lexbuf }`
However, I would like to be able to parse this:

```
stmt;
stmt;
stmt;
expr
expr
expr
```

stmt is defined as follows:

```
stmt :
| ...
| stmt SEMICOLON
```

and my program as this:

```
prog :
| stmt; expr list
```

I would like the `expr` to be interpreted as a list of `expr`. Is there a way to do this? Or would my list have to be separated by other characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [manual](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.pdf) (section 5.4), you can specify a list without any separators easily:

```
prog:
| stmt; list(expr)
```